# dotnet format validation throws dll not found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, dotnet-format

I want to validate the code style of my application according to the .editorconfig. For this task I use a local hosted agent in an azure (2019) ci pipeline. I'm only allowed to use local feeds. So I downloaded [dotnet-format](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-format/) in version 5.1.225507 and added it to the feed.

With the following steps in the yaml pipe I try to validate the code style:

```
# working build and test here...
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet install dotnet-format'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        custom: tool
        arguments: 'update -g dotnet-format --configfile ./.nuget/NuGetBuildServer.Config'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Validiere Codestil'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        custom: format
        arguments: '-v diag --configfile ./.nuget/NuGetBuildServer.Config --check --verbosity diagnostic --no-restore --verify-no-changes --severity info'
# working publishing here...
```

It fails with error that the wrong runtime is installed. How to tell dotnet to use the sdk as runtime? It is installed:

```
[command]C:\dotnet\dotnet.exe --list-sdks
5.0.201 [C:\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: The error tells you **exactly** what the problem is: your agent doesn't have the required .NET runtime version installed.

Comment: yeah but i build for .net 5.0.x and this works fine. Why does this error occur? AFAIK .net core was included in .net 5.0. Do i need to tell him to use another  version?

Comment: Congratulations, your code runs on .NET 5.0. **dotnet-format does not**, hence the error message. **Which you should read.**

Comment: fixed my question. How do i use my installed sdk as runtime? or does the sdk doesn't contain the rutime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. The problem was `dotnet format` looks for the location of the SDK in the default location. The runtime environment was installed in a custom directory instead. To point to the correct version the variable "DOTNET_ROOT" has to be set. Added to the variables:

```
- name: dotnet_root
  value: C:\path\to\.net5.0\
```

This added the variable in the runner.